# AWK/SED/GREP - print M lines after the Nth occurrence of a match

Tags: bash, regex, grep, sed, awk

I am looking to display M lines after the Nth occurrence of a match. Actually I need to do this in order to split a file containing Nth `<regex>` always followed by M lines into Nth different files. I'm under BSD Unix.

```
xyz
<regex>
aa
bb
cc
xyz
<regex>
dd
ee
ff
```

what I want to obtain should be:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

and

```
dd
ee
ff
```

At the moment I'm able to do it correctly printing the M lines INCLUDING `<regex>` with

```
for i in `seq 1 n`; do awk -v n=$i '/<regex>/ && !--n { print ; for(m=1; m<=3; m++) { getline ; print } }' inputfile > outputfile; done
```

I would appreciate any suggestion, as well any simple solution using sed/grep pipes.
Some additional words which explain how the suggested command is working would be additionally appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `display M lines after the Nth occurrence` that doesn't fit your example. But is that what you want: `grep -A3 'regex' inputfile | grep -v 'regex'`?

Comment: I have a file with multiple Nth `<regex>` followed always by the same number of M lines. I would like to split the file into Nth files containing the M lines after matching `<regex>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example file, does this do what you want:

```
$ cat demo.sh
#!/bin/bash

INFILE="./infile"
COUNT=2
OUTFILE_PREFIX="XXX"

sed -n '/regex/,+'${COUNT}' { p; }' ${INFILE} | split -l$((++COUNT)) - ${OUTFILE_PREFIX}

$ ./demo.sh
$ ls XXX*
XXXaa  XXXab
$ cat XXX*
<regex>
aa
bb
<regex>
dd
ee
$
```

Comment: cannot say whether it works or not since, as I specified, I'm under BSD Unix and apparently this script it's for GNU sed